# Python Pickle UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'

Tags: python, pickle

I am having problems unpickling a pickle file for a **chatbot**. This is the code in `training.py`:

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) + "/intents.json")
intents_path = intents_path.replace("\\", "/")
intents = json.loads(open(intents_path).read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ["?", "!", ".", ","] #"'"
for intent in intents["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent["tag"]))
        if (intent["tag"] not in classes):
            classes.append(intent["tag"])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

word_pkl_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) + "/words.pkl")
word_pkl_path = word_pkl_path.replace("\\", "/")
class_pkl_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) + "/classes.pkl")
class_pkl_path = class_pkl_path.replace("\\", "/")
pickle.dump(words, open(word_pkl_path, "wb"))
pickle.dump(classes, open(class_pkl_path, "wb"))
```

This code is based on the code from an older project I made and I remember it working very well back then. The only modification is the relative path with `sys.argv[0]` but i printed the path and it works.

This is in the chatbot, trying to load the pickle file:

```
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    intents_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) + "/intents.json")
    intents_path = intents_path.replace("\\", "/")
    intents = json.loads(open(intents_path).read())

    model_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) + "/words.pkl")
    model_path = intents_path.replace("\\", "/")
    words = pickle.load(open(model_path, "rb"))
    model_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) + "/classes.pkl")
    model_path = intents_path.replace("\\", "/")
    classes = pickle.load(open(model_path, "rb"))
    model_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) + "/commander_model_v1.h5")
    model_path = intents_path.replace("\\", "/")
    model = load_model(model_path)
```

Why is this not working, have they updated the packages enough for this to get the error?

This is the error:

```
words = pickle.load(open(model_path, "rb"))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the actual pickle file old as well? You may want to check the [`pickle` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for the `fix_imports`, `encoding`, and `errors` options.

Comment: no i ran the training.py just an hour or so before running the chatbot

Comment: Unfortunately, pickle isn't very good at telling you where in a file it fails. You could print the file name before the attempted load to make sure its correct and then look at it. I'm not sure if they are big or small, but even opening and printing, say, 256 bytes before the attempted load could be useful to see if its really a pickle file.

Comment: Its unlikely that the loaded file is one of the files written with `pickle.dump`. So we need to figure out whether that in fact is the case.